# JSF PrimeFaces ViewScope without calling init()

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

I have encounter an issue using Primefaces dataTable that is the jsf will call my managed bean **init()** which will do a search from database.

In my jsf, user are able to perform another search which pass an argument in String.

```
<p:commandButton id="btnChild" type="Submit" icon="ui-icon-plus" styleClass="action-buttons" value="Child" update=":frmSysMenu:messages dtSysMenu" ajax="false" action="#{Controller.doParent('C')}" process="dtSysMenu" />
```

my managed bean are able to execute the **doParent(String)** and will go back to the search screen again but once my screen is loaded, it will call **init()** which:

```
@PostConstruct
@Override
public void init(){
    try {
        doSearch(nodeValue,"root");
        setParentNode(nodeValue);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
       Messages.addGlobalError(e.getMessage());
        LOG.error(e.toString(), e);
    }

}
```

and it will gone back to the first query.
is there any other way that I can do?

Does RequestScoped help?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you've solved your problem (congrats), then please post it as an answer. It helps others quickly figuring out that your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank so much! Sorry I am new and thanks for the advice :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF 2.1 View scoped managed bean re-created on every refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153374/jsf-2-1-view-scoped-managed-bean-re-created-on-every-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

From the specs (or somewhere else, OP did not mention it)

> **@ViewScoped**
>   A bean in this scope lives as long as you're interacting with the same JSF view in the browser window/tab. It get
>   created upon a HTTP request and get destroyed once you postback to a
>   different view. It doesn't immediately get destroyed when you
>   leave/close the view by a GET request, but it is not accessible the
>   usual way anymore. JSF stores the bean in the UIViewRoot#getViewMap()
>   with the managed bean name as key, which is in turn stored in the
>   session. **You need to return null or void from action (listener)
>   methods to keep the bean alive.** Use this scope for more complex forms
>   which use ajax, data tables and/or several rendered/disabled
>   attributes whose state needs to be retained in the subsequent requests
>   within the same browser window/tab (view).

in the function I just change to void and jsf won't call the init() again.